# CSS :nth-of-type() Selector for nuxt-link

Tags: css, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get a css menu working but want to use vuejs/nuxt-link instead of a traditional a href as this is a single page application Im trying to learn how to build

I have the following

How do I convert this to work with nuxt-link instead of a href

Thanks

HTML I currently have

```
<nav class="radial">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu" checked>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-question">About</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-book">Resume</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-code">Blog</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-github">Github</a>
  <a href="" class="fa fa-stack-exchange">a</a>
  <label for="menu" class='fa-bars'>Menu</label>
</nav>
```

I'd like to use (for example) in my html, assuming this is possible.

```
<nuxt-link :to="'/about'"><fa icon="bars" /></nuxt-link>
```

The css I currently have is as follows

```
nav.radial {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -2.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0 100px;
}
nav.radial input {
  display: none;
}
nav.radial > label,
nav.radial > a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 3rem;
}
nav.radial label:before,
nav.radial a:before {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
}
nav.radial a {
  color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav.radial label {
  border-radius: 0 0 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem solid #2f2f2f;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: border-bottom 0.25s, box-shadow 0.5s;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ label {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
nav.radial a[href] {
  transition: top 0.1s, left 0.25s, opacity 1s, box-shadow 0.25s;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav.radial a[href]:hover {
  background-color: #E6EDF2;
  border-bottom-color: #2c7768;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href] {
  transition: top 1s, left 0.6s, box-shadow 1s, background-color 0.25s, border-bottom-color 0.25s, border-bottom-width 0.25s;
  opacity: 1;
}
nav.radial a[href]:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 0.25rem;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(1),
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(5) {
  box-shadow: 0 -0.1875rem 0.375rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: -4.72707721rem;
  top: 0.83351125rem;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: -3.08538053rem;
  top: 3.67701333rem;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 0rem;
  top: 4.8rem;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 3.08538053rem;
  top: 3.67701333rem;
}
nav.radial input:checked ~ a[href]:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 4.72707721rem;
  top: 0.83351125rem;
}
```

many thanks for any assistance in advance

Comment: Have you tried assigning a class to your nuxt-link? Something like `<nuxt-link class="nlink" :to="'/about'"><fa icon="bars" /></nuxt-link>` and then replacing all the `a[href]`  for `.nlink` in your css code.

Comment: worked great. thanks, do you know by chance how i can make it so that the menu is closed by default and not open

Comment: You should be able to remove `checked` from `<input type="checkbox" id="menu" checked>` and have it closed by default.